# How to check if a href link has an id or not

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, onclick

I have the below code which tracks clicks on links and then the data feeds into Google Analytics:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('td.rightImage a').click(function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'rightbanner', 'click', $(this).attr('href'),0,true]);
     });
      });
```

At the minute I'm using the href to give each link a unique name but some of the links have ID's which I would prefer to use. How do I check if a link has and ID and use that instead but if a link doesn't have an ID use the href for the unique name instead.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.attr('id')`

```
if($(this).attr( "id" )){
  //id exist
}else{
  //id does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the clicked elements id using the following code line

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('td.rightImage a').click(function(){
          var idHref = (this.id.length) ? this.id : $(this).attr('href');
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'rightbanner', 'click', idHref, 0, true]);
     });
 });
```

---

This way using ternary opetation you can get the id with the preference if that is not available then it will take the href.